# Are there any system tables auto update in postgresql when postgresql server startup?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, auto-update

I want to use Postgresql 9.2.2 to store my applications' data. I had to
build a trigger wich should based on Database level( When the database startup , this trigger will fired and executed.), Are there any tables auto update when postgresql  server startup,  in this way i could create a trigger on this table when server startup!
Thanks a lot and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create triggers on system tables.

Two options occur to me:

1. Do something on application startup, not database startup.
2. Add a "psql" call to the end of the pg-server startup script.